# How to format a Date in a Specific Format in React.js?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to show the full date formatted from this  **2020-11-09T17:50:00.000Z**
to this 
**22/1/2020 14:20:22** format. 
 I know how get the desired format via **moment.js**, but want to achieve this with **JavaScript Date**.
Here is what I have now, but this is not what I want.

```js
let d = new Date("2020-11-09T17:50:00.000Z".toLocaleString("en-US"))
        console.log(d);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The reason moment (and it's replacement luxon) exists is that Date does not do that out of the box. You can do it with string operations and the [Date api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Hi @CharlesBamford thanks for the response. Makes sense. I should have posted my question earlier, I spent a while to find a solution with the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) can produce many formats, and you can choose the locale to get the format (or close to it) that you want.

The locale "en-GB" gives you *almost* what you want; you just need to remove the comma that it puts in...

```js
let d = new Date(2020, 0, 22, 14, 20, 22);
let output = d.toLocaleString("en-GB")
              .replace(',' ,'');
console.log(output);
```

You can actually control the output further by using the [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#using_options) parameter.

But also see the `Intl` object for its [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it manually, the Date API only has a limited set of functions like `.toLocaleDateString()` which will give you "11/9/2020" and `.toGMTString()` will return "Mon, 09 Nov 2020 17:50:00 GMT".

Using your Date APIs, you can build the string yourself using what you have.

```js
var timeString = d.toGMTString().split(" ")[4]; //This will return your 17:50:00
//For the date string part of it
var dateNumber = d.getDate();
var monthNumber = d.getMonth() + 1;
var yearNumber = d.getFullYear();
var dateString = `${dateNumber}/${monthNumber}/${yearNumber}`;
var finalDateString = [dateString, timeString].join(" ");
```